# how to auto sum or automatically calculate when value is inputted in @html.editor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor-2

i have 5 property in the the table its score1 - score5 which are using @html.editor,   how can i  autosum all value inputted in  the @html.editor which will be seen in my other property TotalScore? and it should automatically calculate without submiting or pressing the submit button.

Comment: What is the relevant  HTML rendered by your editor for call ? You can use javascript-jquery to listen to the blur event on the input elements, read the value and sum it and update some other DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

u can use a client side function (javascript) to sum all of ur textboxs data as soon as they all are filled

for example u can add a html class to all of the textbox you want to add and using jquery u can do

```
var Sum = 0;

    $('.myTextBoxs').change(function (){
      $('.myTextBoxs').each(function (){
        var += $(this).val();
       })
    })
```